# ul list layout depending on window width

Tags: css, page-layout

I saw [this page](http://css3clickchart.com/) where, when you change the window width, the layout change with simple animation. Does anybody know the name of this plug-in so I can look for some tutorials? I tried to look at the source code but I can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a plugin -- it's probably using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), which are a part of CSS3.

Comment: really interesting article. I dindn't know this feature. Thanks!